# to verify ID passes through all previous stages

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
id  current stage  previous stages
1      06              05
1      06              03

2      04              03
2      04              02
```

Suppose there are 5 stages of an id (02,03,04 etc). An id should go through each of the stages. Here in the example Id=1 skips 04 and 02 stage but id=2 passes through all. So it should be current stage -1 and -2 etc.

I have to identify such ids which skips stages. I need to do it with a PostgreSQL query.

Comment: Are the stages actually numbered sequentially 2,3,4,5,6? And what's the datatypy of a stage?

Comment: not sequentially. and data type is integer.If the current stage of a ticket is 4 , the previous stages should be 2,3,4 (not necessarily in sequence) but it should not miss any of from 2,3,4.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that current/previous is unique per id:

```
select id
from tab
group by id
having min(previous_stage) <> 2           -- doesn't start with 2
    or max(current_stage) - 2 <> count(*) -- there's at least one missing stage
```

Edit:

Apply `distinct` if `previous_stage` is not unique within `id`:

```
select id
from tab
group by id
having min(previous_stage) <> 2           -- doesn't start with 2
    or max(current_stage) - 2 <> count(distinct previous_stage) -- there's at least one missing stage
```

Edit:

My previous queries had a wrong logic, it should have been `or` instead of `and`.
This should cover you requirements:

```
select id
from tab
group by id
having not
 -- these are the correct ids
 (     min(previous_stage) = 2           -- start with 2
   and max(current_stage) - min(previous_stage) = count(distinct previous_stage)  -- no missing steps
   and max(previous_stage) =  max(current_stage) -1 -- no greater step  
 )
```

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth.But current  stage has one value per id and previous stages can contain same values per id.

Comment: @buntysahoo: Then switch to `count(distinct previous_stage)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: Thanks a lot..The logic worked.Hats off..voted as right

Comment: There is a twist.I Cant use count .This results wrong in some cases.What if current stage is 5.but previous stages are 6,4,2. total 8 stages and an id can take any of the stages even greater also.

Comment: @buntysahoo . . . Then add `where previous_stage < current_stage to your query`.  If that doesn't work, then you should accept this answer -- because it answers this question -- and ask *another* question.  Interpreting "previous stage" as a lower value is a really valid interpretation of the question.

Comment: @buntysahoo: you should have added exceptional data to your question from the beginning.